# Preferences screen using ActionBar Sherlock

Tags: android, preferences, actionbarsherlock

I'm doing an Android application using `ActionBarSherlock`.
My problem is for making preference screen. The `onBuildHeader()` method on the `SherlockPreferenceActivity` class is nerver called.

This is my code

preference_headers.xml

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<header
    android:fragment="package.fragments.MyPreferenceFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/bulle"
    android:summary="An example of some preferences."
    android:title="title" />

</preference-headers>
```

preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:title="@string/options" >

    <PreferenceCategory>
        <SwitchPreference
            android:id="@+id/cb_notif"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="com.vincent.HTC_Dev.pref.notif"
            android:summaryOff="@string/notifications_off"
            android:summaryOn="@string/notifications_on"
            android:title="@string/notifications" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

MyPreferenceActivity

```
public class MyPreferenceActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {


    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        super.onBuildHeaders(target);

        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
    }

}
```

MyPreferenceFragment

```
public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Comment: `onBuildHeaders()` will only be called if you are running on API Level 11 or higher. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC for an example of supporting `PreferenceFragment` on API Level 11+ and classic preferences on older versions of Android.

Answer (score 10):

`onBuildHeaders()` will only be called if you are running on API Level 11 or higher. On older devices, you are back to the classic `addPreferencesFromResource()` approach.

See [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC) for an example of supporting `PreferenceFragment` on API Level 11+ and classic preferences on older versions of Android.

Specifically, its `SherlockFragmentActivity` looks like:

```
package com.commonsware.android.preffragsbc;

import java.util.List;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockPreferenceActivity;

public class EditPreferences extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences2);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
  }
}
```

In `onCreate()` we need to *only* do `addPreferencesFromResource()` *if* we are on an older device. In this case, my sample has two preference headers, and therefore two preference XML files, so we call `addPreferencesFromResource()` on both of them. On newer devices, `onCreate()` does nothing but chain to the superclass, which will trigger the call to `onBuildHeaders()`.

Answer (score 3):

> onBuildHeaders() will only be called if you are running on API Level 11 or higher. See github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC for an example of supporting PreferenceFragment on API Level 11+ and classic preferences on older versions of Android.
>   – CommonsWare Jun 7 '12 at 11:06

@CommonsWare can you please post this as you answer, so I can delete this copy of your answer.